# Setting the stage to scroll horizontally left or right to show content when button is clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a flash site where I have a long horizontal movie clip split into about five sections, each about 960px wide. The effect I want to achieve is when the user clicks on the button it will scroll horizontally to the specific section of the flash project. For example, if your on the home page and you click on the contact the movieclip will tween to the right until it reached the contact section of the long movieclip. And I also want it where if the user clicks on the home it'll scroll back to the home page. I can't seem to accomplish. I tried positioning with the x property and move right so many pixels. I'm thinking about setting like some coordinates or some kinds of reference points so when the button is clicked it will go to those specific points in the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is

1. create a container MovieClip/Sprite add it to stage
2. add all five MovieClips to this container
3. set x positions for each child. child1 - 0, child2 - 960, child3 - 1920, child4 - 2880, child5 - 4800
4. move container to 0, 960, 1920, 2880, 2880 to show child MoviClips 1 to 5 as needed
5. If needed use a library like TweenLite for cool transition

Comment: sweet thanks!!no hopefully whatever I need to add as far as functionality doesn't give me errors